# Persisting strings outside inner loop

Tags: loops, shell, scope, sh

I'm trying to use two loops to check whether a `$new` string is already present within the existlist. However, it doesn't appear that the `$p` string persists outside the inner loop to force the outer loop break.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

#p=0 # The $p string declaration needed to be within the inner loop (below)

while read new; do
   while read exist; do
      p=0 # The $p string declaration needed to be here--resolving the issue
      echo "$new - $exist"

      if [ "$new" = "$exist" ]; then
         #echo "$new - $exist"
         p=1
         break
      fi

   echo "$p" # Test $p string inside the inner loop

   done<existlist

   echo "$p" # Test $p string outside the inner loop

   if [ $p -ne 1 ]; then
      echo "$p"
      break
   fi
done<newlist

echo "#$new#"
```

It is likely a scope issue, but I'm not sure.

While grep would satisfy a file related implementation, it does not necessarily satisfy a non-file based situation. I would like this code to work in both cases.

Comment: `However, it doesn't appear that the $p string persists` Why? `if [ $p -ne 1 ]` don't you want `-eq`? `check whether a $new string is already present within the existlist.` Use something along `grep -xFf newlist existlist`

Comment: There is no scope issue. The standard POSIX dialect has only global variables. Some implementations like Bash have local variables,  which have to be specially declared, and provide dynamic scope, not lexical.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am attempting to evaluate each $new string from the newlist against the entire existlist. If the $new string is not present in the existlist; then, break both loops and continue to use that $new string within the remaining shell code (not included).

Comment: @Kaz I added an `echo $p` line inside and outside of the inner loop to validate the $p string state. It shows that when p=1 in inner loop and breaks, it then is immediately reset to p=0 outside the inner loop. What gives?

Comment: Your `echo` statements don't identify where the output is coming from.  In the program shown, the `echo` inside the nested `while` loop can only ever print `0`, because `p` is set to that value at the top of the loop, and only changed to `1` in an `if` statement which breaks out of the loop (so the `echo`  is not reached).  You have to do something like `echo A $p` ... `echo B $p` ... `echo C $p` ... so you identify the points A, B, C in the source code that are producing the output.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use grep for this?

```
#!/bin/sh
while read MYSTR; do
   grep "$MYSTR" existlist
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "$MYSTR exist in newlist"
     break
   fi
done<newlist
```

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) and the `while` loop would probably also be replaced with a simple Awk script.

Comment: While grep would satisfy a file related implementation, it does not necessarily satisfy a non-file based situation. I would like this code to work in both cases.

Comment: 1. I do not think that testing $? is anti-pattern. We can put grep just inside if statement, but it will be a little harder to read, if your grep command is long enough.

2. if you want, grep can read from stream, just need to modify script for this a little